# Django - Choices vs Models (FKs)

Tags: python, database, django, django-models

Lets say I'd like to give an user options to pick from and ensure that the submitted values are available options.

I've been reading the documentation and it seems to me that: if your values won't change then use `choices` -- if your data is dynamic then use `models`.

I'm a bit unsure though, shouldn't `models` be chosen over `choices` since they enforce some kind of constraint in the DB?

Comment: You don't want a model for simple Gender choices

Answer (score 7):

Use `models` when you **definitely** need one of these:

- ability easily edit (add, delete) choice with no need to reload the code;
- ability to store additional info for any choice;
- easy many-to-many relation (and filtering by it)
- ability to work with dynamic subset of choices in different cases.

Use `choices` otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

`models` enforces constraint via the database. `choices` enforces constraint via the code. Which you choose depends on who you want to select the choices.

Comment: Well yes I mentioned that in my question but -- given the option (db/strategic/performance/etc) shouldn't a constraint in the database be better?

Comment: Why do you believe that a FK must be more performant than a fixed set of values?

Comment: I did not mean that -- performance in the sense that your scenario would allow for an acceptable performance degradation. Thinking a bit more about my question, perhaps I should be asking why  no constraints are placed in the db for choices.